# Gradle - War task: how include into the .war file a specific file from a specific path

Tags: gradle

I am working with a multi module project.

The following is mandatory

```
apply plugin: 'war'

project(':thymeleaf-02-web') {

    description 'Web (HTML, JS, CSS)'

    dependencies {

        exportedProjects.each{
            if("$it"!=":thymeleaf-02-web")
                compile project("$it")
        }

    }

    webAppDirName = 'src/main/resources'

    war {
        version=''
        baseName = warBaseName
    }

}
```

The value for  `webAppDirName`  with `src/main/resources` is totally mandatory, it is not the expected working about with the `WEB-INF` location, because I am working with `Thymeleaf`, otherwise many `@Test` methods fail, it about Testing `@Controller` about `Spring`.

Now I have the mandatory case that I need for the web app the `web.xml` file to configure the `<error-page>`. It is located as usual within the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` location, but when I create the `.war` file and it is deployed the `web.xml` never was taken in consideration and thus is not included.

I have tried the following addition:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/", include: 'web.xml')
    runtime fileTree(dir: "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/", include: 'web.xml')


    exportedProjects.each{
        if("$it"!=":thymeleaf-02-web")
            compile project("$it")
    }

}
```

But nothing. For the moment I must copy/paste *manually* the `web.xml` file into the *deployed* `.war` file.

Thus what is the correct configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `from()` call in your `war` block:

```
war {
    from('src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml') {
        into('WEB-INF')
    }
}
```